# what is the difference between ternary operator ? and IF ELSE?

Tags: apex

i wonder why the below 2 statement return me different result, what is the difference?

tsk.whoid is Contact id.

1)
`system.debug(tsk.whoid.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName() == 'Contact')`

return FALSE

2)

```
if(tsk.whoid.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName() == 'Contact'){
   system.debug ('TRUE');
}else{
   system.debug ('FALSE');
}
```

return TRUE

Thanks,

Comment: Please edit the question to let us have the better clarity as of what you are asking! The title of the question and the description are out of place.

Comment: they should be giving the same result, unless you are querying two different tasks object.

May be run the code in same transaction and with same task object.

Comment: There's no ternary operator in your current example.

Answer (score 3):

Your first code should return true, not false. I suspect there may be a zero-width space or something hidden in your code. I always recommend comparing against SObjectType references:

```
System.debug(tsk.WhoId.getSObjectType() == Contact.SObjectType);
```

This will protect you against accidental typos, since the reference can be validated by the compiler. Do **not** use a describe for this purpose, and avoid using String values when you can help it. Strings are inherently prone to accidents, such as typos.

Answer (score 0):

If going by the title that asks for the difference between the ternary and If-Else, then it is:

Basically for compiler that is, performance. However there will be difference of milliseconds or less if you use ternary than if else that too having the bulk statements.

If you want code maintainability/readability better go for ternary.

Ternary can be used when initializing a variable which cannot be done directly using if else, say

```
Integer i = a<b ? a: b
```

Let me know your queries further!